# TikZ and tikzorbital: problem with background

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemistry

It looks like `tikzorbital` package is not compatible with `background` library of basic TikZ. As you see in the picture below, just `p_y` displayed (do not pay attention to notations in MWE). It displays everything if you switch off the background.

[image]

The MWE is...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} 
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{floatflt}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikzorbital}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,patterns,backgrounds,fit,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[show background rectangle,background rectangle/.style={fill=LightBlue1}]
  \draw[-latex] (0,0)--(1,0) node[above]{\itshape x};
  \draw[-latex] (0,0)--(-0.5,-0.7) node[above]{\itshape y};
  \draw[-latex] (0,0)--(0,1) node[above]{\itshape z};
  \orbital[pos = {(0,0)}]{py}
  \node[above] at (0.7,0.7) {p$_x$};

  \draw[-latex] (3,0)--(4,0) node[above]{\itshape x};
  \draw[-latex] (3,0)--(2.5,-0.7) node[above]{\itshape y};
  \draw[-latex] (3,0)--(3,1) node[above]{\itshape z};
  \orbital[pos = {(3,0)}]{px} 
  \node[above] at (3.7,0.7) {p$_y$};

  \draw[-latex] (6,0)--(7,0) node[above]{\itshape x};
  \draw[-latex] (6,0)--(5.5,-0.7) node[above]{\itshape y};
  \draw[-latex] (6,0)--(6,1) node[above]{\itshape z};
  \orbital[pos = {(6,0)}]{pz}
  \node[above] at (6.7,0.7) {p$_z$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Test} \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Is there any ways around?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is quite simple: [`tikzorbital`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzorbital) makes itself use of the `background` layer. This means that a couple of your drawings are on the same layer.

You can solve the problem by declaring a further layer and set it behind the `background` one. This can be done with `\pgfdeclarelayer` and `\pgfsetlayer` commands.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}% no need in this mwe
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}% no need in this mwe
\usepackage{float}% no need in this mwe
\usepackage{floatflt}% no need in this mwe

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikzorbital}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,patterns,backgrounds,fit,arrows}
\pgfdeclarelayer{backbackground}
\pgfsetlayers{backbackground,background,main}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[font=\itshape]% to not type it every time, but better go for math mode
  \draw[-latex] (0,0)--(1,0) node[above]{x};
  \draw[-latex] (0,0)--(-0.5,-0.7) node[above]{y};
  \draw[-latex] (0,0)--(0,1) node[above]{z};
  \orbital[pos = {(0,0)}]{py}
  \node[above] at (0.7,0.7) {p$_x$};

  \draw[-latex] (3,0)--(4,0) node[above]{x};
  \draw[-latex] (3,0)--(2.5,-0.7) node[above]{y};
  \draw[-latex] (3,0)--(3,1) node[above]{z};
  \orbital[pos = {(3,0)}]{px} 
  \node[above] at (3.7,0.7) {p$_y$};

  \draw[-latex] (6,0)--(7,0) node[above]{x};
  \draw[-latex] (6,0)--(5.5,-0.7) node[above]{y};
  \draw[-latex] (6,0)--(6,1) node[above]{z};
  \orbital[pos = {(6,0)}]{pz}
  \node[above] at (6.7,0.7) {p$_z$};
  \end{scope}

  % correctly setting the background layer
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{backbackground}
  \fill[LightBlue1](current bounding box.south west)rectangle
  (current bounding box.north east);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Test} \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]