# TikZ and tikzorbital: bacground and caption fill width correspondence

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds, chemistry

Current question related with my other question, [TikZ and tikzorbital: problem with background](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210451/tikz-and-tikzorbital-problem-with-background). In prevous question, the problem with layers has been decided:

[image]

All I need is just fill rectangle width becomes to `\columnwidth`. If you are interesting, why I need it, I use the filled caption, and I need booth picture fill width and caption fill width becomes to `\columnwidth`. However you don't need to create the filled caption in MWE: use the text as measure.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}% no need in this mwe
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}% no need in this mwe
\usepackage{float}% no need in this mwe
\usepackage{floatflt}% no need in this mwe

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikzorbital}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,patterns,backgrounds,fit,arrows}
\pgfdeclarelayer{backbackground}
\pgfsetlayers{backbackground,background,main}

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\oddsidemargin=-10.4mm  %     
\evensidemargin=-20.4mm %
\topmargin=-24mm        %
\textwidth=190mm        %
\textheight=275mm       %
\headheight = 5mm      %
\headsep = 4mm
\footskip = 8mm

\begin{document}
\twocolumn

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[font=\itshape]% to not type it every time, but better go for math mode
  \draw[-latex] (0,0)--(1,0) node[above]{x};
  \draw[-latex] (0,0)--(-0.5,-0.7) node[above]{y};
  \draw[-latex] (0,0)--(0,1) node[above]{z};
  \orbital[pos = {(0,0)}]{py}
  \node[above] at (0.7,0.7) {p$_x$};

  \draw[-latex] (3,0)--(4,0) node[above]{x};
  \draw[-latex] (3,0)--(2.5,-0.7) node[above]{y};
  \draw[-latex] (3,0)--(3,1) node[above]{z};
  \orbital[pos = {(3,0)}]{px} 
  \node[above] at (3.7,0.7) {p$_y$};

  \draw[-latex] (6,0)--(7,0) node[above]{x};
  \draw[-latex] (6,0)--(5.5,-0.7) node[above]{y};
  \draw[-latex] (6,0)--(6,1) node[above]{z};
  \orbital[pos = {(6,0)}]{pz}
  \node[above] at (6.7,0.7) {p$_z$};
  \end{scope}

  % correctly setting the background layer
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{backbackground}
  \fill[LightBlue1](current bounding box.south west)rectangle
  (current bounding box.north east);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{This is the test of the caption} \end{figure}

\lipsum[3-7]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a dummy node with a `minimum width=\columnwidth` to fill across the column. Similarly, enclose the caption inside a node with some adjustments. On the other hand, if you are loading `caption` package, you may use `\captionof` macro too.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}% no need in this mwe
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}% no need in this mwe
\usepackage{float}% no need in this mwe
\usepackage{floatflt}% no need in this mwe

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzorbital}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings,patterns,backgrounds,fit,arrows}
\pgfdeclarelayer{backbackground}
\pgfsetlayers{backbackground,background,main}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\oddsidemargin=-10.4mm  %
\evensidemargin=-20.4mm %
\topmargin=-24mm        %
\textwidth=190mm        %
\textheight=275mm       %
\headheight = 5mm      %
\headsep = 4mm
\footskip = 8mm

\begin{document}
\twocolumn

\lipsum[1-2]

\begin{figure}[ht!]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[font=\itshape]% to not type it every time, but better go for math mode
  \draw[-latex] (0,0)--(1,0) node[above]{x};
  \draw[-latex] (0,0)--(-0.5,-0.7) node[above]{y};
  \draw[-latex] (0,0)--(0,1) node[above]{z};
  \orbital[pos = {(0,0)}]{py}
  \node[above] at (0.7,0.7) {p$_x$};

  \draw[-latex] (3,0)--(4,0) node[above]{x};
  \draw[-latex] (3,0)--(2.5,-0.7) node[above]{y};
  \draw[-latex] (3,0)--(3,1) node[above]{z};
  \orbital[pos = {(3,0)}]{px}
  \node[above] at (3.7,0.7) {p$_y$};

  \draw[-latex] (6,0)--(7,0) node[above]{x};
  \draw[-latex] (6,0)--(5.5,-0.7) node[above]{y};
  \draw[-latex] (6,0)--(6,1) node[above]{z};
  \orbital[pos = {(6,0)}]{pz}
  \node[above] at (6.7,0.7) {p$_z$};
  \end{scope}
  \node[minimum width=\columnwidth] at (current bounding box.center){};   %% this node is dummy

  % correctly setting the background layer
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{backbackground}
  \fill[LightBlue1](current bounding box.south west)rectangle
  (current bounding box.north east);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \tikz[baseline=1ex]\node[text width=\columnwidth,fill=LightBlue1,text height=-2ex,inner sep=0pt]{\caption{This is the test of the caption This is the test of the caption This is the test of the caption}};   %% caption inside a node.
  \end{figure}

\lipsum[3-7]

\end{document}
```

[image]